# QGraphicsView inside QPlainTextEdit (scrollable widget)

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qplaintextedit

I have a `QGraphicsView` with icons inside `QPlainTextEdit`. View sticks fine to `QPlainTextEdit`'s size and scrolls too, the problem is to set the height of the `QGraphicsScene` to the height of the view.

Scene size is set to match the view, with `setSceneRect()`, but has no effect.
I colored the view with violet and scene with red to be sure.

[image]

Can you help me with this setback, please? I haven't found anyone with similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was setting `viewport()->setSceneRect()` instead of `viewport()->setSize()`. It works now.